# changing the font size of the suggestion part of jquery ui autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jquery ui v.1.12.1, autocomplete  . how can I increase the font size of the suggestion part, I added the font-size to the   .ui-menu .ui-menu-item   of css , but nothing changed. I changed the font-size  for   .ui-widget .ui-widget   but nothing changed. how can I changed the font size of the suggestion?

Comment: Use CSS to target those classes. If it didn't work then you most likely need to increase the rule specificity so that it overrides the default styling. Unfortunately as you've not added any code which recreates the issue, this is just a guess.

Comment: As suggested, you can do it via more specific CSS. An alternative is to use `_renderItem` callback. https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem